# Python - Modify for-loop variable

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this function:

```py
numbers = [3, 4, 6, 7]

for x in numbers:
    a = 5 - x
    b = 5 + x
    c = 5 * x
    print(x, a, b, c)
```

What it exactly does doesn't matter, only the x is relevant.

I want modify x so that:

```py
for x in numbers:
    a = 5 - (x + 2)
    b = 5 + (x + 2)
    c = 5 * (x + 2)
    print((x + 2), a, b, c)
```

But obviously adding `+ 2` everywhere is annoying, so I just want to have another value for `x`.

Of course, I could make another variable like this:

```py
for x in numbers:
    modifiedX = x + 2
    a = 5 - modifiedX
    b = 5 + modifiedX
    c = 5 * modifiedX
    print(modifiedX, a, b, c)
```

But I'm curious if I could get the same result without adding another line, like:

```py
for x + 2 in numbers:
    a = 5 - x
    b = 5 + x
    c = 5 * x
    print(x, a, b, c)
```

or this:

```py
x + 2 for x in numbers:
    a = 5 - x
    b = 5 + x
    c = 5 * x
    print(x, a, b, c)
```

The last 2 code blocks aren't correct Python syntax, so I'm curious: Is there is a correct method out there to have a modified version of `x` without adding more lines?

**Note:** I still want to keep the original numbers list, so I'm not looking for changing the numbers in the list directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` to generate a new iterable that contains the elements of `numbers` incremented by 2. Since `map()` creates a new iterable, the original list isn't modified:

```py
numbers = [3, 4, 6, 7]

for x in map(lambda x: x + 2, numbers):
    a = 5 - x
    b = 5 + x
    c = 5 * x
    print(x, a, b, c)
```

This outputs:

```py
5 0 10 25
6 -1 11 30
8 -3 13 40
9 -4 14 45
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works if you want a short answer:

```
numbers = [3, 4, 6, 7]
[print(x, 5-x, 5+x, 5*x) for x in map(lambda x: x + 2, numbers)]
```

Output:

```
5 0 10 25
6 -1 11 30
8 -3 13 40
9 -4 14 45
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension can work

```
for x in [y+2 for y in numbers]:
    a = 5 - x
    b = 5 + x
    c = 5 * x
    print(x, a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

The things being done to `x` can be wrapped into a function.  This function will perform the series of actions being done to x and print the results.

```
def do_things(x):
    a = 5 - x
    b = 5 + x
    c = 5 * x
    print(x, a, b, c)
```

Then you can loop through the defined values and call the function with x unchanged

```
numbers = [3, 4, 6, 7]

for x in numbers:
    do_things(x)

3 2 8 15
4 1 9 20
6 -1 11 30
7 -2 12 35
```

Or you can modify the value of x as you call the function:

```
for x in numbers:
    do_things(x+2)

5 0 10 25
6 -1 11 30
8 -3 13 40
9 -4 14 45
```